# Get corresponding dial code for country on hover using jVectorMap & JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jvectormap

I have a JSON file containing countries, with their corresponding dial codes (For example, +1 for US, +44 for UK).

I'm looking to display the correct dial code for that country on hover using jVectorMap

How can this be achieved? The code I have so far is below, but this simply displays the first dial code in the JSON file for every country.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        countryCode = data[0].dial_code;
    });

    $('#focus-single').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 'GB');
    });
    $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', ['GB', 'FR']);
    });
    $('#focus-multiple2').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', ['GB', 'IT']);
    });
    $('#focus-init').click(function(){
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 1, 0, 0);
    });
    $('#map1').vectorMap({
        backgroundColor: ['#D3D3D3'],
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
            label.html(label.html() + ' (' + code.toString() +  ')<br>' + countryCode);
```

Reference:

This is the JSON file I'm using: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/1c2b972438c88480b23bdb44c0469bc56010d470/CountryCodes.json

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting `countryCode` to be the dial code of the first index.

```
countryCode = data[0].dial_code;
```

`countryCode` needs to be set to the dial code of the specific country. What you need to do is parse the JSON as a whole, finding the country's index within the JSON by its code, then finding the dial code of said country. Something more along the lines of this:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    countryCode = data;
});

onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    var data = JSON.parse(countryCode );
    var index = data.map(function(d) { return d['code']; }).indexOf(code);
    var dialCode = data[index].dial_code;
    label.html(label.html() + ' (' + code.toString() +  ')<br>' + dialCode)
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfritsch/qsp9kx38/) that should help visualize what is going on.